# set value for other userform controls on userform close

Tags: excel, excel-2010, userform, vba

really struggling with this one, found a solution for the time being but it's not really a satisfactory one.
I have a workbook with two user forms, one to input data and one to search for previously entered data and a third user form designed as a date picker form which is set to activate on entry of a designated date text box.

Individually I have no problem, the user clicks the text box and the date picker form appears, they make their selection which closes the date picker form and adds the date to the text box. On the "input data" form I have a multi page with a single date selection text box on each of the two pages, on the "find data" form I have an option to search a single date or a range, 3 date selection text boxes in total.

now I am noticing that userform1 (input data) is prompting a run time error 91 - object variable or With block variable not set and is flagging the first line for userform2 in the code whenever I select a date from the date picker form.

what I did notice however was that the correct date was still being entered into the textbox so as a fix I added an 'On error goto' line above the highlighted line which is allowing the action to take place without interruption. What I did notice was that now if I enter a date anywhere on userform2 (find data) and then close the form and decide I want to enter data instead, the text box on userform1 will contain whatever the previous selection was on userform2. What is especially puzzlng about this to me is that the initialize event for UF1 enters the current date in the date text box.

see code below, is there a much better way to write this? I hope I explained well enough, please let me know if I can provide additional details to help.

```
Sub CloseDatePicker(save As Boolean)

  If UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0 Then
  UserForm1.tbDate.Text = Calendar1.Value
  UserForm1.cbMember.SetFocus
  ElseIf UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 1 Then
  UserForm1.tbDate2.Text = Calendar1.Value
  UserForm1.cbMember2.SetFocus
 End If

 On Error GoTo dpexit

If UserForm2.ActiveControl.Name = "TextBox1" Then
UserForm2.TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.Value
End If
 If UserForm2.ActiveControl.Name = "TextBox2" Then
 UserForm2.TextBox2.Text = Calendar1.Value
 ElseIf UserForm2.ActiveControl.Name = "TextBox3" Then
 UserForm2.TextBox3.Text = Calendar1.Value
 End If

dpexit:
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you hiding UserForm2 or unloading it?

Comment: both userforms 1 and 2 are set to `unload me`. but the issue is occurring when the userform `DatePickerForm` is closing, not userform1 or userform2.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a file as example. Let me know if it would really help to understand what I'm running into.

Answer (score 0):

Right out the gate, the first problem I see with your code is you're trying to change the value of a text box with the `.Text` property. I've personally never had luck with using `.Text` to set value as it consitently throws `Err:91`. Instead I've found it's better to use `.Value`.

```
Sub CloseDatePicker(save As Boolean)

    If UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0 Then
        UserForm1.tbDate.Value = Calendar1.Value
        UserForm1.cbMember.SetFocus
        ElseIf UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 1 Then
        UserForm1.tbDate2.Value = Calendar1.Value
        UserForm1.cbMember2.SetFocus
    End If

' On Error GoTo dpexit 'disabled this for you to test your code

    If UserForm2.ActiveControl.Name = "TextBox1" Then
        UserForm2.TextBox1.Value = Calendar1.Value
    End If
    If UserForm2.ActiveControl.Name = "TextBox2" Then
        UserForm2.TextBox2.Value = Calendar1.Value
    ElseIf UserForm2.ActiveControl.Name = "TextBox3" Then
        UserForm2.TextBox3.Value = Calendar1.Value
    End If

dpexit:
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, if you're trying to edit these values on a userform that's been unloaded, there won't be anything to reference. Using `.Hide` would be better form all around until you're completely done using the userforms.